# Adding a url column in celltable gwt

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-celltable

I'm workin on a web app using gwt, I have a  celltable with textcolumns
I want to add a column that will contain links, once the user clicks on a cell of this column he is forwaded to the link.

How can I do such a thing in gwt?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a cell of appropriate type such as [ClickableTextCell](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ClickableTextCell.html) or [ButtonCell](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ButtonCell.html) as well as a [FieldUpdater](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/FieldUpdater.html).

Basically you can add a FieldUpdater to your column as such:

```
column.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<YourObject, String>() {
        @Override
        public void update(int index, YourObject object, String value) {
            Window.open(value, "_blank", ""); //This will open link in a new tab or window
        }
    });
```

Where value in this case is the url. update() will be called when the column is clicked.